# join a separate table to woocommerce products table where values of the second table can align with SKU

Tags: mysql, woocommerce

I found this [code](https://gist.github.com/yanknudtskov/f2660cbe81a4eff404e161688b5169a4) for getting product info from the woocommerce store via a mysql query instead of wpdb queries and it works flawlessly.

However, I have another table I would like to join specific columns to this one. The second table has identical SKU values so they could be joined by that. However I cannot seem to figure out how to join them nicely based on the SKU of the product for Table 2 (wp_table_extra). I keep getting `no rows` error in AriAdminer so at least my syntax isn't wrong, but I cannot join the additional column that I want. my plan is to use this elsewhere (outside of woocommerce) hence why I cannot use the built in hooks.

Here is what I have gotten so far;

```
SELECT
     /** Post ID **/
     p.id,
     /** Product Code **/
     mt.meta_value AS sku,
     /** Product Stock **/
     m.meta_value AS stock,  
     /** Item Price **/
     pt.meta_value AS price,
     /** EXTRA ITEMS **/
   wpte.extra AS extra
FROM
     wp_posts AS p
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta m ON (
     p.id = m.post_id
)
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta mt ON (
     p.id = mt.post_id
)
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta pt ON (
     p.id = pt.post_id
)

JOIN wp_table_extra wpte ON (
p.id = wpte.sku
)
WHERE
 p.post_type = 'product'
AND
 m.meta_key = '_stock'
AND
 mt.meta_key = '_sku'
AND
 pt.meta_key = '_price'
AND
wpte.details = 'extra info'
```

Comment: `p.id` is the post ID; are you sure it equals to `wpte.details` as in `ON (p.id = wpte.details)` ?

Comment: @SallyCJ It doesnt, but what I am trying to do is use the SKU since the other table is coded with the SKU and not the post ID ... so the joining feature would be the SKU

Comment: How about `ON (mt.meta_value = wpte.sku)` ?

Comment: Yeah, tried that ...

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Are you sure `ON (mt.meta_value = wpte.sku)` doesn't work? Because it worked for me. My table structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xy8aO.jpg and sample data: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9fzP.jpg and the SQL query I used and its result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtEvQ.jpg